# How can we switch between two sorting algorithms based on their run time performance?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

I am trying to write a program which will take an input array as input and will sort it.
Sorting will be like this :

Program will start sorting the first 20% of the array using any of the below mentioned sorting algorithms. If after 20%, program identifies that the sorting algo is taking worst case time, the program will switch to the other sorting algorithm and continue sorting the array using that sorting algorithm.
The problem i am facing here is how to know whether the sorting algorithm is taking worst case time or not ?

The sorting algos i'll be using are :

Quicksort,
Mergesort,
Bucketsort

Any kind of help would really be appreciating.

Comment: Look up "introsort".

Comment: For bucket sort, you could look for the distribution of elements across the buckets. For quicksort, you could look at the position of the pivot after the partitioning step. Merge sort has the same worst-case complexity as it's average complexity, so it's not really suitable as the first algorithm in this hybrid approach.

Comment: Counting the number of inversions will cost *only* one linear pass.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "sorting the first 20%" of the array?

I think whatever you mean requires having a sorted version of the array first so that you can check how much the array is sorted. Then how do you come up with the sorted version without having to sort the array first? It's like a chicken and egg problem.

Back to your main question, as far as I remember most sorting algorithms have their run-time complexity analyzed based on the number of copy operations. For example insertion sort requires many copy operations as you have to shift elements when you need to insert an element at the right place. Other algorithms are analyzed based on the number of swap operations, which can also be broken down to as 3 copy operations.

However, as I noted above, I don't know how you define an array as x% sorted and don't know how you could measure such level of sortedness without having a sorted array first.

Comment: sorting the first 20% of the array means..if i have an array of length 100. i'll first pick a sorting algo randomly and then sort first 20 elements of the algo after that i have to identify the performance of the algo and if it is not giving worst case execution time i'l continue sorting or else i'll switch to some other algo..but the thing is that how can i know whether the algo is giving worst case or not.

Answer (score 0):

Use heap sort worst case time complexity nlogn and constant space.

Answer (score 0):

First, quicksort is preferred algorithm for arrays, while merge is preferred for lists, mainly because mergesort needs O(N) additional memory.

One solution to you problem may be to first do the quicksort, and then each split you first check how many different elements do you have in your part of the array. If that number is comparatively small you then do bucketsort, otherwise continue quicksort.

To find the threshold you can make a large test set of randomized arrays of different length and distribution and compare the performance of quick sort and bucket sort. When making test arrays try to simulate your usage scenario as much as possible. That way you can to some degree of error determine the threshold for the number of different elements in the array.

In most cases I used the threshold ~1000 different elements, however this is extremely dependent of your usage scenario, so performing test is the best option.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am planning  to pick the first algorithm randomly and once the algo sort the first 20% of the array, i'll have the time complexity with me and the execution time as well. Now i am stuck here because i cannot compare time complexity with actual execution time to switch to other algorithm.